# How to move the times sign under the exponent?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'd like the `\times` symbol to be under the exponent in the following example, how can I achieve this ?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{k+1} \times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

I tried to use `\smashoperator` but failed to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally would not do that but since you are asking...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\mathrlap{k+1}} \times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that ?

Comment: @Rphad This is only a personal opinion which you may ignore. I personally would not add the `\times` here and would put the bracketed expression in the numerator of the fraction that follows. If you put the `k+1` on top of the `\times` it looks a bit like a math operator like a sum with some limits and I personally would try to  avoid this possible confusion.

Answer (score 10):

I could understand a desire to avoid the hole, but your readers would have a hard time in interpreting the expression if the exponent is completely above `\times`.

I'd possibly use (3) or (4), but would prefer (5), removing the `\times` altogether, or better yet (6).

Notice the `\!` in the exponent to avoid the other hole.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}\times\frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}
\mspace{-\medmuskip}
\times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}
\mspace{-1.5\medmuskip}
\times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}
\mspace{-2\medmuskip}
\times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}
\frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\!k+1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can do this with the `\rlap` command.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{k+1}{k^\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{\rlap{$\scriptstyle{k+1}$}} \times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems now to be some additional interest in typesetting this equation, let me spell out [my above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540080/move-sign-under-exponent/540083#comment1364341_540083).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
     \frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}\frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
     \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
     \frac{\dfrac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think, though, that all these are off-topic as they do not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\mathrlap` from `mathtools. Adding some mayj kening, one can have the × symbol under the + in the exponent.

Comments aside: loading `inputenc` is not necessary nowadays, since LaTeX expects utf8 by default, and amsmath  is already loaded by `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{k+1}{k^{\frac{k}{k+1}}}\right)^{\mkern-6mu \mathrlap{k+1}}\mkern 1.5mu\times \frac{1}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]